# Output not correct for my C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, palindrome

So, I have the following problem:

1. From the file tabl.in a number **n** will be read (n<=50).
2. After that a square array with **n** rows and **n** columns will be read; all the numbers in the array will be composed by a maximum of 2 digits each.
3. Shown in the file tabl.out, the modulo between the sum of numbers found on the second diagonal of the array and 10, if the sum is palindrome (true=1, false=0), and the arithmetic mean of elements situated below of the main diagonal.

Will be writing functions for:

- reading the array
- calculation of the operation sum of secondary diagonal%10
- checking if the previous result it is palindrome
- calculation of the arithmetic mean below main diagonal

Example:

**tabl.in**:

```
4
5 8 2 12
1 0 3 16
1 2 1 11
5 7 2 19
```

**tabl.out**:

```
2 1 3
```

where 
(12+3+2+5)%10 = 22%10 = 2
22 is palindrome = 1
1+2+2+1+7+5 = 18, 18/6=3

My code so far is:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("tabl.in");
ofstream fout("tabl.out");

void readn(int Arr[][51], int n) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            fin >> Arr[i][j];

}

int sumsec(int Arr[][51], int n) {

    int s = 0;
    float r;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        s = s + Arr[i][n - i + 1];
    r = s % 10;
    return r;

}

void pald(int Arr[][51], int n) {

    int s = 0, pal = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        s = s + Arr[i][n - i + 1];
    while (s != 0) {
        pal = pal * 10 + s % 10;
        s = s / 10;
    }
    if (pal == s)
        fout << "1 ";
    else
        fout << "0 ";

}

int ambmd(int Arr[][51], int n) {

    int s = 0, k;
    float ame;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            s = s + Arr[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    ame = s / k;
    return ame;

}

int main() {

    int Arr[51][51], n;
    float r, ame;
    fin >> n;
    readn(Arr, n);
    r = sumsec(Arr, n);
    fout << r << " ";
    pald(Arr, n);
    ame = ambmd(Arr, n);
    fout << ame;

}
```

But I have an issue with the `palindrome()` function: my output file will have `2 0 3` written to it for the given array from the example, instead of `2 1 3`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `pald()` need the array for?

Comment: palindrome function for the modulo resulted after operation of sum for elements from secondary diag divided to 10. You will find the answer to algorithm in top of the code: (12+3+2+5)%10=22%10=2....22 is palindrome=1

Comment: Any reason you are not using `std::vector` (or even `std::array`) instead of C-arrays? Beside the stream operators, this is C code, not C++.

Comment: What I meant was you are calculating `22` two times. Why not reuse?

Comment: Off topic: what's your plan for `n` = 2147483641?

Comment: i need the solution for this pattern.
@user4581301I told you my number n must be <=50!!!!

Comment: I think you put comment here just because is impossible for you to solve that... comments without thinking

Comment: OK. What's your plan for `n` = -1?

Comment: @user4581301 what array can you build with n=-1????????? You want to prove what? Please stay away if you don't read the problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pald` function would work, if you compute `s` the same way as you do in `sumsec` and if `s` would still contain the sum, after you compute `pal`.

In your case, `while (s != 0) {...}`, followed by `if (pal == s) {...}` could be re-written as `if (pal == 0)`, which is clearly not the intended solution. Just save your sum before computing `pal`, then compare with the saved sum.

Also, change your loop condition for computing `s` to `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`.

```
int s = 0, pal = 0, sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    s = s + Arr[i][n - i + 1];
sum = s;
while (s != 0) {
    pal = pal * 10 + s % 10;
    s = s / 10;
}
if (pal == sum)
    fout << "1 ";
else
    fout << "0 ";
```

You should also consider the various comments for code improvements, like not re-computing the sum in the `pald` function.

Comment: @DanielCraick sorry, missed the part about computing the sum, because I checked your palindrome-algorithm with a pre-made sum. Edited to explain the other mistake.